# Can i make an stackedInline connnection between two model without having any connection between them ? in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = model.TextField()

class Photo(models.Model):
    item = models.ChaField(max_length=250)
    title=models.ChaField(max_length=250)
```

here is admin.py

```
class PhotoInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Photo

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PhotoInline]

admin.site.register(Item,strong text ItemAdmin)
admin.site.register(Photo)
```

i want to have an inline connection between without them having any relationship

Comment: But why? If they have a relationship, then model that relationship.

Comment: For some reason I have to make inline form of two model which do not have any kind of relationship. I can't make it either